# Laravel "undefined array key 0" that is actually defined

Tags: php, laravel, object, if-statement

This is really weird. Laravel is telling me "undefined array key 0" but I am able to echo the value that Laravel can't seem to see and I can assign it to a variable.

```
$progress_check = db::select("select submitted, signed_off from users_to_stages where user_id = ? and sop_id = ? and stage_id = ?", [Auth::user()->id, $id, $do_stage_object->id]);
$thing = $progress_check[0]->submitted; // <-- $progress_check[0]->submitted contains 1

echo $thing;
exit;
```

And I get `1` returned from `$thing`. No errors. But! This:

```
$progress_check = db::select("select submitted, signed_off from users_to_stages where user_id = ? and sop_id = ? and stage_id = ?", [Auth::user()->id, $id, $do_stage_object->id]);
$thing = $progress_check[0]->submitted;

if($thing) {
    $do_stages[$do_stage_object->id]['submitted'] = 1;
} else {
    $do_stages[$do_stage_object->id]['submitted'] = 0;
}
```

Gives "Undefined array key 0" on the `$thing = ...` line that previously threw no error and successfully outputted the value (of 1).

If it helps, here's the `print_r` and `dd` of `$progress_check`:

```
print_r($progress_check);
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [submitted] => 1
            [signed_off] => 0
        )

)

dd($progress_check);
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#644 ▼
    +"submitted": "1"
    +"signed_off": "0"
  }
]
```

I'm no expert on Laravel or object-oriented PHP (or object-oriented anything else for that matter) so maybe I'm just missing something I should know? Another pair of eyes was equally stumped though so... more eyes please!

I should mention, I'm running Laravel 8.83.22.

Edit: using `db::table` instead in line with ItsGageH's answer gives the same error and same situation with still being able to echo / assign it (as long as I don't then use if in an `if`) but slightly different contents in the DB results:

```
print_r($progress_check);
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [submitted] => 1
                    [signed_off] => 0
                )

        )

    [escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => 
)
```

Edit: bonus points (imaginary points though) if anyone can tell me what that 644 is?

Comment: With `0` you mean to get the first entry, right? Then try instead: `$thing = reset($progress_check)->submitted;`

Comment: @Top-Master thanks but that gives `Attempt to read property "submitted" on bool` but you are right - I only want the first entry. I'm only ever expecting a single row returned for this query (just to check two DB fields).

Comment: That error means `reset` did return `false`. Basically, you should ask "why is my query sometimes returning no result" instead of above.

Comment: I'll read up on reset() (never encountered it before) but there's no "sometimes" about this one - I can try 100 times and it's the same every time. The query does fetch data successfully and I can echo it and assign it to a variable (which I can also echo).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table first, before the Select statement, then use `where` and `get`

So, you'd be looking at doing:

```php
DB::table('users_to_stages')
->select('submitted, signed_off')
->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
->where('sop_id', '=', $id)
->where('stage_id', '=', $do_stage_object->id)
->get();
```

Further Laravel select-statement reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements)

Comment: Well that's a different way of doing the same thing. `db::select` just runs a query almost like you'd write directly in MySQL / MariaDB. It works correctly and fetches the data I need. This is still definitely appreciated though because although it doesn't really answer the question it definitely might provide a workaround and get my code working. Hopefully somebody can explain what's going on though!

Comment: I'm afraid I end up with the same error. `$progress_check` ends up slightly different but I think essentially the same (updated question with result).

Answer (score 0):

The answer "Undefined array key 0" means you haven't define any first element with the 0 key. For instance: `[0 => Auth::user()->id]`

It seems you can workaround the problem without the [0] at $progress_check:

```
$progress_check = db::select("select submitted, signed_off from users_to_stages where user_id = ? and sop_id = ? and stage_id = ?", [Auth::user()->id, $id, $do_stage_object->id]);
$thing = $progress_check->submitted;

if($thing) {
    $do_stages[$do_stage_object->id]['submitted'] = 1;
} else {
    $do_stages[$do_stage_object->id]['submitted'] = 0;
}
```

Your bonus point:
644 is about the permission of reading or writing files, depending of what have been set up with chmod. This choice is often chosen, don't care about it.